# Extracting sentences which contain specific words using count in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have a long text. I want to extract only the sentences which contain at least one of the words found in a list.

```
list1 = ["apple", "orange", "tomato"...]
text = "I would love an apple. It is a nice day. How are you? Tasty orange..."
```

I thought of doing something like this:

```
sentences_with_fruits = []
for sentence in split_into_sentences(text):
    if sentence.count(list1) > 0:
        sentences_with_word.append(sentence)
```

I received the following error:

> must be str, not list.

Any ideas on how to solve this or perhaps a better way to get the same result?

Comment: What does `split_into_sentences` return? Also add the full traceback. It tells us much more than "must be str, not list".

Comment: split_into_sentences returns sentences from the text.

Comment: That makes sense -- but are you sure it is not necessary to providve a [mcve]? What about the second part of my comment? It will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the word and sentence tokenizers from NLTK Library.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
list1 = ["apple", "orange", "tomato"]
text = "I would love an apple. It is a nice day. How are you? Tasty orange..."
sentences_with_word = []
for sen in sent_tokenize(text):
    l = word_tokenize(sen)
    if len(set(l).intersection(list1))>0:
        sentences_with_word.append(sen)
```